# Using VCorpus() function but lose content

Tags: r, tm

I am using the `VCorpus()` function in `r` package `tm`. Here is the problem I have

```
example_text = data.frame(num=c(1,2,3),Author1 = c("Text mining is a great time.","Text analysis provides insights","qdap and tm are used in text mining"),Author2=c("R is a great language","R has many uses","DataCamp is cool!"))
```

This looks like

```
num                             Author1               Author2
1   1        Text mining is a great time. R is a great language
2   2     Text analysis provides insights       R has many uses
3   3 qdap and tm are used in text mining     here is a problem
```

Then I type `df_source = DataframeSource(example_text[,2:3])` to only extract the last 2 columns.

`df_source` looks correct. After that, I did `df_corpus = VCorpus(df_source)` and `df_corpus[[1]]` is

```
<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 2
```

And `df_corpus[[1]]` gives me

```
$content
[1] "3" "3"
```

But `df_corpus[[1]]` should return

```
<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 49
```

And `df_corpus[[1]][1]` should return

```
$content
[1] "Text mining is a great time." "R is a great language"
```

I don't know where goes wrong. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: From `help(DataframeSource)`, a data frame source interprets each row of the data frame x as a document. I think you should treat each sentence as one document, and have to convert your data.frame with 6 rows, 1 column (the sentence) before you use `DataframeSource`.

Comment: @kitman0804 it was a `datacamp` interactive exercise. I did that in the web browser, and it correct output what as expected. However, when I did that in my r studio on my laptop, it generates this problem.

Comment: Add argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when you create `example_text`, then everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The texts inside `example_text` that are supposed to be character have all become factors because the 'factory-fresh' value of `stringsAsFactors` is `TRUE`, which is weird and annoying from my point of view.

```
example_text <- data.frame(num=c(1,2,3),Author1 = c("Text mining is a great time.","Text analysis provides insights","qdap and tm are used in text mining"),Author2=c("R is a great language","R has many uses","DataCamp is cool!"))
lapply(example_text, class)

# $num
# [1] "numeric"
# 
# $Author1
# [1] "factor"
# 
# $Author2
# [1] "factor"
```

To ensure the column Author1 and Author2 to be character columns, you may try:

1. Add `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` at the beginning of your code.
2. Add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` inside your `data.frame(...)` statement.
3. Run `example_text[, 2:3] <- lapply(example_text[, 2:3], as.character)`
4. Run `example_text[, 2:3] <- lapply(example_text[, 2:3], paste)`

Then everything should work fine.